# Copy EXIF meta data from the Keywords to the Description on a huge amount of photos in sub folders

Tags: exif, file-metadata

I have over 80,000 photos that have been given proper EXIF keywords but Google Drive requires data in the Description for it to be searchable in their online app. I need to copy the contents of the Keywords entry to the description on this mass of photos that goes deep into sub directories.

Comment: You can use combination of find utility and ExifTool: http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/ to get and after write this info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) you could just run:

```
exiftool -TagsFromFile file.jpg '-Keywords>Description' file.jpg
```

You can find more info in [the manpage for exiftool.](http://man.cx/exiftool)

Comment: Great thanks for pointing me in the right place. I finished the rest of it so that it does them in batch and goes to all sub folders
`exiftool −r −overwrite_original -TagsFromFile @ '-Keywords>Description' *`

Answer (score 0):

snowliondev's solution pointed me in the right place. It works on jpg's using the legacy IPTC:Keywords tag, but the following command will apply to jpg, png and other files with XMP tags:

```
exiftool −r −overwrite_original -TagsFromFile @ '-XMP:Subject>Description' *
```

See [this thread](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php/topic,8536.0.html), which also shows how to include the directory path in the description metadata which is helpful for Google Photos which does not preserve folder hierarchies.